# How to create two \newcommands from one variable #1?

Tags: macros

Consider the following code snippets:

a) Text to be printed in some document using command `\defPrimitiveRoots`

```
 \Snippet{\defPrimitiveRoots}{Integers with primitive roots}{
     Let $n,k$ be integers, and $p$ a prime. Then $n$ possesses primitive roots if and only if $n$ is of the form $2, 4, p^k$ or $2p^k$.
 }
```

b) A further call to `\srem`

```
 \newcommand{\Snippet}[3]{
     \newcommand{#1}{
         \srem{#2}{
             #3
         }
     }
 }
```

c) A further call to the `\shadedrem` environment.

```
 \newcommand{\srem}[2]{
     \begin{shadedrem}
         \textbf{#1} \newline #2
     \end{shadedrem}    
 }
```

Finally, in a document the text is written with

```
 \defPrimitiveRoots
```

I want to automatically make two commands 1) `\cshPrimitiveRoots` ( which is the same as `\defPrimitiveRoots above` ) and 2) `\beaPrimitiveRoots` where the text is formatted such that it prints nicely on a `beamer` slidesheet.

Question: I suppose I have to change this part of the code

```
 \newcommand{\Snippet}[3]{
     \newcommand{#1}{
         \srem{#2}{
             #3
         }
     }
 }
```

to something like:

```
 \newcommand{\Snippet}[3]{
     % #1 = defPrimitiveRoots this should become cshPrimitiveRoots 
     % PrimitiveRoots is of course a variable.
     \newcommand{#1}{
         \srem{#2}{
             #3
         }
     }

     % #1 = defPrimitiveRoots this should become beaPrimitiveRoots 
     \newcommand{#1}{
     % I know how to do setup for beamer slide here.
     }
 }
```

How is this done?

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear, but I think you mean `\expandafter\newcommand\csname csh#1\endcsname{....}` etc.

Comment: Apparently my solution was useless to you, so I deleted it -- it was working for me but due to code unavailable to me of no use to you :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SnippetA}[3]{% 
  \@namedef{csh#1}{\srem{#2}{#3}}% 
  \@namedef{bea#1}{\srem{#2}{ #3 }}%
}% 

\newcommand{\Snippet}[3]{%
     % #1 = defPrimitiveRoots this should become cshPrimitiveRoots 
     % PrimitiveRoots is of course a variable.
  \@namedef{csh#1}{\srem{#2}{#3}}%
     % #1 = defPrimitiveRoots this should become beaPrimitiveRoots 
  \@namedef{bea#1}{%
       % I know how to do setup for beamer slide here.
     }%
 }
\makeatother
\providecommand\srem[2]{%
  This is the first argument: #1\par
  This is the second argument: #2}  

\begin{document}

\Snippet{PrimitiveRoots}{Arg one}{Arg two}

\SnippetA{APrimitiveRoots}{Arg one}{Arg two}

\cshPrimitiveRoots

\beaPrimitiveRoots

\cshAPrimitiveRoots

\beaAPrimitiveRoots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am going to try this.

Comment: defPrimitiveRoots is in .tex file and uses a package topics which contains the \Snippet command the topics package uses \input to read the actual definition snippet text. - I added the SnippetA code and everything compiles. Then I defined the snippet using SnippetA and I got an undefined control sequence in the snippet definition file.

Comment: give a _complete_ example

Comment: I think I got it working now :-) If in error I update the question with all the files.

Comment: I got it working, thank you very much for answering.